# Is there any way to tell VSCode my absolute paths

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am developing a React application whose environment is created using `create-react-app` and I added and I have the following folder structure:

```
src
 |- components
 |- styles
       |- config.scss
       |- reset.scss
       |- common.scss
 |- index.ts
```

in the middle of the `common.scss` file I use `@use "src/styles/config.scss"` and it works great, the preprocessor itself sees all the changes and functions from there, but not VSCode when I press **Ctrl + Left Click**, it throws me an alert with the inscription *"Unable to open 'config'"* and this complicates the development, since it does not see what functions are there and does not allow me to view them on my own when autocomplete is not working, I have to open folders and search for the file itself every time.

And here is the question, is it possible to somehow explain to **VSCode** that this `@use "src/...."` is the root of the src folder, since I checked the work in **WebStorm**, it works there itself, and it easily recognizes the paths and where they lead, I would like and here is such an opportunity (

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below codes in jsconfig.json. These codes define absolutely path as src. But I am not sure the codes makes to click to link references.

````
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "src"
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"],
    "include": ["src"]
  }
  ```
````

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did so, so the compilers and preprocessors work great, but for some reason VSCode itself does not see this( So the question here is how to specify VSCode so that it also understands baseUrl